# Sacar los elementos repetidos de un Lista y ponerlos en otra Lista

Tags: c#, linq

Hola buena tarde a todos

Tengo una lista que se crea de una clase Alumno la cual cuenta con nombre, apellido y edad y necesito identificar los campos que se repiten con LINQ y pasar a otra lista los registros repetidos ya de ahí poder contar el total y mostrar cuantas veces se repiten los valores.

Esta es la lista:

```
var alumno = new List<Alumno> 
        { 
            new Alumno
            {
                Nombre = "Luis",
                Apellido = "Martinez",
                Edad = 30
            },
            new Alumno
            {
                Nombre = "Luis",
                Apellido = "Martinez",
                Edad = 30
            },
            new Alumno
            {
                Nombre = "Jesus",
                Apellido = "Flores",
                Edad = 30
            },
            new Alumno
            {
                Nombre = "Juan",
                Apellido = "Rosales",
                Edad = 30
            },
            new Alumno
            {
                Nombre = "Pedro",
                Apellido = "Perez",
                Edad = 30
            },
            new Alumno
            {
                Nombre = "Pedro",
                Apellido = "Perez",
                Edad = 30
            }
        };
```

La cual proviene de esta clase

```
public class Alumno
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apellido { get; set; }
    public int Edad { get; set; }
}
```

Pero necesito sacar los datos repetidos en una nueva lista y que la lista quede más o menos así.

```
var alumnoRepetidos = new List<Alumno> 
        { 
            new Alumno
            {
                Nombre = "Luis",
                Apellido = "Martinez",
                Edad = 30
            },
            new Alumno
            {
                Nombre = "Luis",
                Apellido = "Martinez",
                Edad = 30
            },
            new Alumno
            {
                Nombre = "Pedro",
                Apellido = "Perez",
                Edad = 30
            },
            new Alumno
            {
                Nombre = "Pedro",
                Apellido = "Perez",
                Edad = 30
            }
        };
```

Espero me puedan ayudar.
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Te propongo esta solución:

```
var listaA = (from a in alumnos group a by new
              {
                  a.Nombre, 
                  a.Apellido, 
                  a.Edad
              } 
              into g
              select new
              {
                  Nombre = g.key.Nombre,
                  Apellido = g.key.Apellido,
                  Edad = g.key.Edad,
                  Total = g.Count()
              }).ToList();
```

Aquí hago una consulta en donde agrupo por nombre, apellido y edad y obtengo una lista de objetos donde además de mostrar los campos anteriores muestro, el total de veces que ese alumno se repite.

Después si quisieras como solo quieres mostrar los duplicados harías esto:

```
var listaB = (from l in ListaA
              where l.Total > 1
              select l).ToList();
```

Aquí obtengo una lista de los alumnos que aparecen más de una vez, o sea duplicados. Te sugiero que investigues sobre el **group by** en internet.

Comment: Hola @LuisMtz podrías decirme si te sirvió la respuesta, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Propongo otra alternativa con linq también:

```
 var lista_salida = alumno.GroupBy(i => new { i.Nombre, i.Apellido, i.Edad }).Where(i => i.Count() > 1).SelectMany(i=>i);
```

1- Agrupamos con la cláusula GroupBy usando de claves los tres parámetros que se pueden añadir o quitar.

2- Discrepamos por el número de repetidos usando la cláusula Where.

3- Unimos Las listas resultantes en una sola con todos los datos usando la cláusula SelectMany.